# How do I add curly brackets to f-strings in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I have this code

```py
class = "maximum"
s = f"""The code for {class} is {3854-st56}"""
print(s)
```

I want this to output:

```
>> The code for maximum is {3854-st56}
```

But the f-string doesn't recognize the curly brackets around 3854-st56 and instead thinks I am trying to input actual Python code. How do I make the f-string recognise that the curly brackets are string literals.

Answer (score 10):

To escape curly braces, duplicate them:

```
>>> x="abc"
>>> f"{x} {{x}}"
'abc {x}'
```

You can also look at the PEP for more information: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#escape-sequences

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `curly bracket` twice if you are assigning variable value and once if you are putting on a value:

```
Class = "maximum"
s = f"""The code for {{{Class}}} is {{'3854-st56'}}"""
print(s)
```

---

```
The code for {maximum} is {3854-st56}
```

Comment: Use double braces {{ or }} so your code becomes:

sb.AppendLine(String.Format("public {0} {1} {{ get; private set; }}", 
prop.Type, prop.Name));

// For prop.Type of "Foo" and prop.Name of "Bar", the result would be:
// public Foo Bar { get; private set; }